# Maps/Battles system in Unity using Mirror (Dofus-like)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, scene, unity3d-mirror

I've been thinking at the best way to implement a **system of "maps"** (like *DOFUS*) using **Mirror** (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PvfohUbfp90&t=2s if someone wants to see a better insight on what I'm talking about, just the first 30/40 seconds)

Each map will be a scene. The players can only see/chat with the other players in the same map (thus same scene).

Now comes the problem with battles: a player can start a battle with a NPC. The player and the NPC will disappear (in the other players clients) while fighting.  But that still happens on the same terrain, same grid.
So I've thought about several solutions:

1. Make each battle happens in another scene, created at runtime? but that seems overkill
2. Z-Stack the player & the monster and create another terrain at runtime (so it will be in the same scene, just further on the Z axis so other players can't see the player & NPC in battle anymore)
3. Disable Network Visibility for the player & NPC in battle for the other players present in the scene

Any advice on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider making a new scene-- what if you have 1000 people in same map all in battles? I would think it would be best save the players coords,load a scene,do the battle, destroy scene, throw player back to original coords.